# Drawing on image with the GD library in PHP

Tags: php, image, gd

I have created a code to generate a random pattern image. it creates an image with given width and height and fills it with small 40x40 pixel rectangles.
this is my code:

```
<?php 

$width = 1000; 
$height = 600;

$image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
$baseR = 255 - rand(0, 100);
$baseG = 255 - rand(0, 100);
$baseB = 255 - rand(0, 100);

for ($i = 0; $i <= floor($width / 40); $i++){
for ($j = 0; $j <= floor($height / 40); $j++){
  $val = floor(100 * (rand(0, 100) / 100));
  $r = $baseR - $val;
  $g = $baseG - $val;
  $b = $baseB - $val;
  $color = imagecolorallocate($image_p, $r, $g, $b); 
  imagefilledrectangle($image_p, $i * 40, $j * 40, (($i + 1) * 40), (($j + 1) * 40), $color);

}
}

imagejpeg($image_p, 'my_dir/test.jpg');
```

?>

there's no problem when i set the width to a value like 640 and the height to 400. but if i set the width to 1000 and the height to 800, there will be a blank area on the right side of the image which is not covered by rectangles.
I implemented the same code in delphi and it worked perfectly, but in PHP...!

Comment: is this blank area some multiple of 40 in size? if so, then there's some kind of math/fencepost error. if it's a wonky non-40x size, then something very weird is going on.

Comment: I don't think so because i even used this code and it didn't work either:
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++){
  for ($j = 0; $j <= 1000; $j++){

Comment: I think it should be `<` rather than `<=` but can't test that.

Comment: I even tested that! it just works very nice and smooth in Delphi! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `imagecreate` to `imagecreatetruecolor`

You're creating a palette based image with 255 colors max. You're running out of colors to allocate at the end and it's recycling the last color on the palette for the remainder of the blocks.