# create an image with circle pattern with GD library in PHP

Tags: php, gd

There is an excellent code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395843/) which produces images similar to the following example, using **PHP GD** library. The image is basically a repeated `square pattern`.

[image]

I need to create similar images BUT with `circles pattern` but am unable to do so as I am still learning. I tried to modify the code using `imagefilledellipse`.

```
$width = 1000; 
$height = 600;

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
$baseR = 255 - rand(0, 100);
$baseG = 255 - rand(0, 100);
$baseB = 255 - rand(0, 100);

for ($i = 0; $i <= floor($width / 40); $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j <= floor($height / 40); $j++){
        $val = floor(100 * (rand(0, 100) / 100)); //value will always be within the range of 1-100
        $r = $baseR - $val;
        $g = $baseG - $val;
        $b = $baseB - $val;
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image_p, $r, $g, $b); 
        imagefilledellipse($image_p, $i * 40, $j * 40, ($i * 40), ($j * 40), $color);
    }
}

imagejpeg($image_p, uniqid() .'.jpg');
```

---

The result is horrible.  Although I understand rest of the code, this line `imagefilledellipse($image_p, $i * 40, $j * 40, ($i * 40), ($j * 40), $color);` is beyond me. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```
imagefilledellipse($image_p, $i * 40, $j * 40, ($i * 40), ($j * 40), $color);
```

by

```
 imagefilledellipse($image_p, $i * 40, $j * 40, 40, 40, $color);
```

[image]